# XCTAssertEqual on string allways fails

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays, unit-testing, swift3

I am trying to parse a dictionary into a NewsItem object. 
`XTAssert("testString" == "testString")` or `XCTAssertEqual("testString", "testString")` does not fail. I use Swift 3 and Xcode 8.0.

[image: NewsItemTests]

```
XCTAssert(s == t) //Also fails
```

I parse newsItem.newsPreamble like so

```
let newsPreamble: String

...
self.newsPreamble = dictionary["NewsPreamble"] as? String ?? ""
```

Comment: Any hidden characters? Check `print(s.data(using: .utf8)! as NSData)` for both strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your debugger output

```
(lldb) po (s.data(using: .utf8)! as NSData)
<e2808be2 808b7465 73745374 72696e67>
```

one can see that the string has two "invisible" characters,
`E2 80 8B` is the UTF-8 sequence for `U+200B` which is the
"ZERO WIDTH SPACE".

Removing white space at the start (and end) would be one possible
solution:

```
var s = "\u{200B}\u{200B}testString"
print(s) // testString
print(s.data(using: .utf8)! as NSData) // <e2808be2 808b7465 73745374 72696e67>
print(s == "testString") // false

s = s.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
print(s == "testString") // true
```

Answer (score 0):

s and t had different encodings (I think)

running

```
(lldb) po (s.data(using: .utf8)! as NSData)
<e2808be2 808b7465 73745374 72696e67>

(lldb) po (t.data(using: .utf8)! as NSData)
<74657374 53747269 6e67>
```

made it clear. Thanks @Martin R

Comment: Swift strings  work transparently with Unicode, you cannot have a "`String` with a different encoding". The encoding becomes only relevant when you convert a string to data (bytes) or back.